# Disable secure logon for tablets connected to domain

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

I have a domain set up with Windows 2008 R2, and by default requires Ctrl + alt + del to unlock computers. I have been pulling my hair out trying to configure GPO so that tablets will not require Ctrl + alt + del. Is it possible to target specific computers and apply certain group policy settings?

Comment: Are the tablets joined to the domain?

Comment: Yes they are since they are requiring the Ctrl alt del to log in. I am looking to disable this requirement for tablets only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a group policy setting:

Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options: Interactive logon: Do not require CTRL + ALT + DEL

However, unless you're able to apply a WMI filter to detect tablets, you'll probably have to put the tablets in a special OU and apply the policy to that OU.

I feel like I should point out that, you know.  It's usually considered a good idea to require Control-Alt-Delete to log on.  This setting is usually disabled by default (meaning control-alt-delete is *required*) in domain settings and left blank for stand-alone workstations, so this policy might exist in your default domain policy settings.